# Why aren't my files getting added

Tags: git, gitlab

I am trying to add two files to a local gitlab (academic clone of git hub) repo and then them push to a remote gitlab repo's master branch.

I use these commands, which run without error but don't add the file to the remote repo.

```
a$ git add slides1.pptx 
a$ git add slides2.pptx 
a$ git push origin master
Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS gitlab ssh-pty

Everything up-to-date
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to commit:

```
a$ git commit -m "Added 2 *.pptx files"
```

and only after you have committed you can push your changes to remote:

```
a$ git push origin master
```